# PyTorch DataLoader

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to use multiple `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`s to create datasets that have different transforms applied to them. Currently, my code is roughly

```python
d_transforms = [
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    # Some other transforms...
]
loaders = []
for i in range(len(d_transforms)):
    dataset = datasets.MNIST('./data', 
            train=train, 
            download=True, 
            transform=d_transforms[i]
    loaders.append(
        DataLoader(dataset, 
            shuffle=True, 
            pin_memory=True, 
            num_workers=1)
        )
```

This works, but it's extremely slow. [kernprof](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) shows that nearly all of the time in my code is spent on lines like

```
x, y = next(iter(train_loaders[i]))
```

I suspect that this is due to the fact that i'm using multiple instances of `DataLoader`, each with their own worker, which tries to read the same data files.

My question is, what is a better way to do this? Ideally, I would subclass `torch.utils.data.DataSet` and specify the transform i'd like to apply *when sampling*, but this doesn't seem possible due to `__getitem__` not being able to take arguments.

Answer (score 2):

`__getitem__` does take an argument which is the index of the content you want to load . For eg.

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     normalize])

class CountDataset(Dataset):

def __init__(self, file,transform=None):

    self.transform = transform
    #self.vocab = vocab
    with open(file,'rb') as f:
        self.data = pickle.load(f)
    self.y = self.data['answers']
    self.I = self.data['images']


def __len__(self):
    return len(self.y)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    img_name = self.I[idx]
    label = self.y[Idx]
    fname = '/'.join(img_name.split("/")[-2:]) #/train2014/xx.jpg
    DIR = '/hdd/manoj/VQA/Images/mscoco/'
    img_full_path = os.path.join(DIR,fname)
    img = Image.open(img_full_path).convert("RGB")
    img_tensor = self.transform(img.resize((224,224)))
    return img_tensor,label


testset = CountDataset(file = 'testdat.pkl',
                        transform = transform)


testloader = DataLoader(testset, batch_size=32,
                         shuffle=False, num_workers=4)
```

You dont call the data loader in loop.